# Unable to run the playwright tests

Tags: javascript, npm, playwright

I am trying to run `playwright` test from the below location, but it shows the message `npm install -D @playwright/test` and unable to run the test. I have already installed `playwright` as dev dependency. Could someone please advise what is the issue here ?

I have tried below runs:

1)

```
Test User@TestUser MINGW64 /c/Test
    $ npx playwright test --headed
    Please install @playwright/test package to use Playwright Test.
      npm install -D @playwright/test
```

2. Test User@TestUser MINGW64 /c/Test
   $ npx playwright test
   Please install @playwright/test package to use Playwright Test.
   npm install -D @playwright/test

// test/test1.spec.js

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const title = page.locator('.navbar__inner .navbar__title');
  await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
});
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "play",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Playwright test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx playwright test"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did `npm install -D @playwright/test` show any errors? What are the node and npm versions you are using? It might be a bug related to running this under mingw, can you file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw guys are recommending a couple of suggestions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/playwright/issues/6981)

1. Delete the playwright module.

   `npm rm playwright`

   `npm install @playwright/test -D`
2. Use yarn  `npx playwright test` -> `yarn playwright test`
3. And I solved the issue in my Gitlab pipeline with adding this to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```html
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions but didn't work for me straight forward. I did the below workaround that worked for me

Steps

- npm uninstall playwright playwright-chromium
- Delete manually *@playwright/test* line from dev dependency section of package.json file
- npm update
- npm install -D @playwright/test